# Two separate click event having different functionality for same button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, requirejs

I sam using requireJS to generate the code Dynamically and also load the elements whenever the need,
i've two javascript classes that using same UI (html) elements, 
Now i want bind the click event in two classes for same button.
two classes having completely different functionality in button triggers

HTML Code

```
<div class='command-processor'>
    <div class='left-control' id='left-control'>
        <img src='images/options.png' class='ctrl-image'/>
    </div>
    <div class='controls'>
        <span class="previous" id="previous"><</span>
            <input type='text' name='text-control' id='text-control' />
            <span class="next" id="next">></span>
        <input type='button' id='send' value='send' />
    </div>
    <div class='right-control' id='right-control'>
        <img src='images/options.png' class='ctrl-image'/>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS Code**
*class1 = View*

```
// some stuff

_data=$("#user-input").val();
$(".command-processor").off("click","#send");
$(".command-processor").on("click","#send",function()
{
    f.sendData(_data,dest);
});
```

*class2 = Field*

```
$(".command-processor").off("click","#send");
$(".command-processor").on("click","#send",function()
{
    var data=[];
    var item={};
    if(this.fieldData)
    {
        for(i=0;i<this.fieldData.length;i++)
        {
            item[this.fieldData[i].FieldName]=this.fieldData[i].DefaultValue;
        }
        data.push(item);
        var _data = JSON.stringify(data);
        f.sendData(_data,dest);
        this.fieldData=null;
    }
});
```

When First Class **View** is loaded to the browser, the class click event for send button works well,
and also the second class **Field** is loaded to the  browser, the class click event for send button works well.

after first class works are finished, i am loading the second class from my time class..

In Second class, when send button triggers , once its completes the send button functionality execution finished,
i want to activate the first class **View** click Event For Button

*Thanks in Advance !* awaiting responses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your second class, send button click triggers, after execution of click event, call the method from first class which re-initialize the events in first class.. 
Second Class:

```
$(".command-processor").off("click","#send");
$(".command-processor").on("click","#send",function()
{
    var data=[];
    var item={};
    if(this.fieldData)
    {
        for(i=0;i<this.fieldData.length;i++)
        {
            item[this.fieldData[i].FieldName]=this.fieldData[i].DefaultValue;
        }
        data.push(item);
        var _data = JSON.stringify(data);
        f.sendData(_data,dest);
        this.fieldData=null;
        ctrl.trigger("ReInitialize",[]);
    }
});
```

First Class

```
ctrl.on("ReInitialize",function(event,info)
{
       this.initEvents();
});
```

this is sample code to work between classes and prototypes